# displaying multiple div's using anchors tag

Tags: jquery, html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#listjobsDiv" id="listJob">listJobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#newJobDiv" id="newJOB">Add new Job</a></li>
    <li><a href="#editJobDiv" id="editJOB">Edit Job</a></li>
    <li><a href="#deleteJobDiv">Delete Job</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="adminBody">
    <div id="listjobsDiv" style="display:none">List Jobs Here</div>
    <div id="newJobDiv" style="display:none">New Job Here</div>
    <div id="editJobDiv" style="display:none">Edit Job Here</div>
    <div id="deleteJobDiv" style="display:none">Delete Job Here</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to display  one of the `div` in `adminBody` section, when I click the respective links using jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#newJOB").click(function() { 
        alert('newJob'); 
        $("#newJobDiv").css('display', 'block'); 
    });  
});

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#editJOB").click(function() { 
        alert('hi'); 
        $("#editJobDiv").css('display', 'block');   
    });  
});
```

But the problem is when I click the links the previous div's are also displaying in `adminBody` div.

Comment: yes, the previous div's will display,  where you are hidding these

Answer (score 1):

You should hide them first then show only the interesting one.

Something like `$("div[id$='Div']").hide()`

Note: This will select all div with ID finishing by 'Div'. You may want to be more precise on this

Answer (score 0):

The other div's are also displaying because their display property is still `block`. You need to set the other div's css to `display:none`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: how does it not answer the question? he says the previous ones display too. so i am saying you need to set their display property to none. do i have to give full code for each answer?

Comment: Your answer very much looks like comment rather than answer, describe your answer is more detail, and if you can't better don't answer questions..

Comment: @OSSCubeSolution i haven't even put a single link in this answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide the previous divs again.

```
$("#adminBody div").hide();
```

And you can .show() and hide() instead.

```
 $("#newJobDiv").show();
```

Take a look at this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bmems/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $div = $(this).attr('href');
     $('#adminBody').children().hide();
     $('#adminBody').find($div).show();
  });  
});
```

#### [Tryout fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rSNf/)

Comment: Wouldn't this hide the links and not the divs?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you rename your `listJobsDiv` to `listJobDiv`, then name your last link to `deletejob`:

`<li><a href="#deleteJobDiv" id="deleteJob">Delete Job</a></li>`

Then you can do something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var adminBody = $("#adminBody");
        $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function () {
            adminBody.find('div').hide();
            var id = this.id;
            $("#" + id + "Div").show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: as per your  code all the div are displaying when i click the any of the link

Comment: Er, my bad, I updated my answer to include `"#"`, should work now